# How to show a form from a thread different than the ApplicationContext thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am trying to make a windows application that start in the system tray as a `NotifyIcon` and then shows some forms based on events and user input. 
I'm using Visual Studio 2013

So what I did is delete the default form VS creates and delete the `Application.run()` from `Program.cs` and did `Application.run(new MyApplicationContext())` where `MyApplicationContext` is a class that extends `ApplicationContext` where I initialize and show the `NotifyIcon`

Then I made a woker thread that queries a database for information and tries to show that information in a `NotificationForm` that I created.

If I do something like this in the woker thread code:

```
NotificationForm form = new form();
form.Top = // change the location;
form.show();
```

The notification shows in the default position, and any UI element on it appears transparent and I can see-through to desktop

But if I call `Application.run(form)` in the worker thread the form works right and shows in the right position, but it blocks my worker thread.

If I had a `Form` I would call `Invoke` on that `Form`. But what am I supposed to do in my case?

**EDIT:** As a workaround I initiated a `Form` called `parentForm` in the `MyApplicationContext` then called show on it then made it invisible. And then I invoke from that. But it seems a dirty work around and not the right one;

Comment: Any comment why I deserve the down-vote so I could at least improve?

Comment: Have you tried simply spinning up a new thread and running `Application.Run(form);` on that thread?

Answer (score -1):

```
        BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker;

    private void Init()
    {
        _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += _backgroundWorker_DoWork;

        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0);

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(10);
    }

    private void _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.Text = "Percentage:" + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        form.Show();
    }
```

I didn't test it, but it might works like that.